# How to change the fontsize of captions of floats inside a tcolorbox?

Tags: captions, tcolorbox

I am using `tcolorbox`, and changed `fontupper=\bfseries\large` in order to have larger main texts. But when inserting a **float of figure**, the fontsize of its caption is not changed. How to change the **fontsize of the caption of floats** simultaneously and exactly the same with the `fontupper`, in particular, in the global settings (since I have inserted a number of tcolorboxes as well as floats of figures)? In other words, I wish to have **all** the text inside the tcolorbox exactly the same features (fontsize, color, etc.).

The prototype of my tex file is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter

\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\begin{document}
    \newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter]{cBoxE}[1][]{enhanced, breakable, fontupper=\bfseries\large, title=Example}
    
    This is a test.
    
    \begin{cBoxE}[This is a test]{}
        
        Here is a figure.
        
        \begin{figure}[H]
            \begin{centering}
                \includegraphics{figure}
                \par\end{centering}
            \caption{The caption of this figure.}
            
            \label{thisfig}
        \end{figure}
    \end{cBoxE}
    
\end{document}
```

The output of the above code is
[image]

I want to have something like:
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could use the caption package to temporarily change the caption font.

Some other comments:

- are you really, really sure that your file is encoded in `latin9`? That would be highly unusable. Most modern editors will use `utf8`
- `\centering` is a macro, not an environment
- if you don't want your figure to float, e.g. in your tcolobox, don't place it in a floating environment like figure. Instead you can add a caption via the `\captionof` macro from the caption package
- no need for the `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` pair around the tikz libraries

```
\documentclass[a4paper,english]{revtex4-2}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
%\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}

\tcbuselibrary{skins,breakable}

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}

\newtcolorbox[auto counter, number within=chapter]{cBoxE}[1][]{enhanced, breakable, fontupper=\bfseries\large, title=Example, code={      \captionsetup{font={large,bf,color=red}}},coltext=red}

This is a test.

\begin{cBoxE}[This is a test]
  Here is a figure.
  \begin{center}
    \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
    \captionof{figure}{The caption of this figure.}
    \label{thisfig}
  \end{center}
\end{cBoxE}

\begin{figure}[htbp]
  \centering
  \includegraphics{example-image-duck}
  \caption{The caption of this figure.}
  \label{thisfiga}
\end{figure}    

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! It works quite well in my case!

Comment: @panda.G You're welcome!